# Problems with css styles in nuxt3

Tags: css, assets, nuxt3

I am working on a project with nuxt3 and the truth is that I have had some problems with the styles. I have my assets/css/sidebar/style.css folder which contains my styles for my sidebar.

style.css (example):

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap");

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --main-color: white;
  --main-color-dark: #0026EB;
  --main-color-light: #5872f5;
  --main-color-light-2: #dbe8fd;
  --text-color: #0026EB;
  --text-color-span: white;
  --main-color-span: #2563EB;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: #e4e2f5;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
```

I use it in my PlSidebard.vue component like this:

```
<style>
@import "@/assets/css/sidebar/style.css";
</style>
```

then i use in component in my index.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="rounded-full">
        <PlSidebar></PlSidebar>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  import PlSidebar from '~/componentes/main/PlSidebar.vue';
  export default {
    components: { PlSidebar }
  }
  </script>
```

me da como resultado:
[image]

Now the problem I have is that what I do in the other views, they are displayed, let's say, in the same space of my sidebar, instead of being displayed on the entire screen, I have this in my other view, a calendar:

```
<template>
  <h1 class="custom-title font-black">Calendario</h1>

  <Calendario></Calendario>
</template>

<script>
import Calendario from "~/componentes/main/Calendar/Calendario.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    Calendario,
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.custom-title {
  max-width: 110rem; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  padding: 20px; 
  font-size: 36px;
}
</style>
```

and it shows me like this:
[image]

I tried placing scoped in my PlSidebard component but it didn't work for me, since it makes my sidebar lose styles, and even so it doesn't solve the problem.